# Intersection of orbits of earthquake flow on Teichmüller space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, teichmuller-theory, lorentzian-geometry

Let $\Sigma$ be a closed oriented surface of genus $g\geq2$. We consider $\mu$ and $\nu$ two filling measured laminations on $\Sigma$. (We say that $\mu$ and $\nu$ fill $\Sigma$ if $\Sigma\setminus(\mu,\nu)$ is a disjoint union of open topological disks). Steven Kerckhoff gives the following characterization of the filling in terms of the length of $\mu$ and $\nu$, which we denote by $l_{\mu}$ and $l_{\nu}$ respectively.

**Theorem (Kerckhoff 1992)** Let $\mu,\nu$ two measured laminations. Then $l_{\mu}+l_{\nu}$ has a unique critical point on $\mathcal{T}(\Sigma)$ (which is a minimum) if and only if $\mu$ and $\nu$ fill $\Sigma$.

Using this result Caroline Series prove the following

**Theorem (Series 2012)** Let $\mu,\nu$ two measured laminations which fill $\Sigma$. Let $c>0$ and $\mathcal{H}_{\mu,c}=\{p\in\mathcal{T}(S)\mid l_{\mu}=c\}$. Then $l_{\nu} $ has a unique critical point on $\mathcal{H}_{\mu,c}$, which is a minimum. We denote this point as $m_{\mu,\nu,c}$.

**My question is the following:** If $E_{l}^{\mu}(p)=E_r^{\nu}(p)$ for some $p\in \mathcal{T}(\Sigma)$, where $E_l^{\mu}$ and $E_r^{\nu}$ means the left (respectively, right) earthquake along the measured lamination $\mu$ (resp $\nu$), is it necessary that the minimum point $m_{\mu,\nu,c}$ belongs to $\left\{E_l^{t\mu}(p)\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$? (Where $c=l_{\mu}(p)$).

By definition it belongs to $\mathcal{H}_{\mu,c}$ but I don't know on which orbit of the earthquake flow this point belongs to.

Thank you very much.